# How can I add a network drive to the system to see the available storage as I do with the root folder

Tags: mount, nautilus, samba, gnome-shell-extension, cifs

I want to know if its possible to add a network drive to nautilus or (in my case) to [Gnome system-monitor extension](https://github.com/paradoxxxzero/gnome-shell-system-monitor-applet).
Right Now I am writing in the fstab file the following lines:

```
//IP-of-the-server/folder/ /mnt/server cifs username=*****,password=**** defaults 0 0
```

What I am trying to do is to see the available storage and the used one in the following parts of the screenshots. I have already installed the `cifs-utils` package.

Drives are samba ones. Sorry if the screenshots are in low quality, I am trying to fix that too.

[image: Here are the screenshots]

[image: Here are the screenshots]

Thank You so so much.

Comment: Two questions for you: (0) which version of Ubuntu are you running (1) does the network share currently mount correctly at boot?

Comment: (0) I am using last LTS Ubuntu Version: "20.04".
(1) Yes, I already fixed the problem on the gnome system-monitor extension. So it rest just to see it on Nautilus as a "normal" drive, Like when I plug in one external drive. I don't know if this can be done with a network drive, I hope so..., Thank You so much. At least I have it already on the extension, but I will appreciate if can be possible to do the same on Nautilus.

PD: I followed the following post: "https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide".
This worked on the extension, but did not work on Nautilus. Thanks again.